# Storing images on server

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I am new to backend programming. I am working on a personal Full stack project where I display all my art works. These art works are lot of images. I read up in some articles that it is better to save files on server than on database. I am using MEAN stack for my application. Can anyone refer me to some links or help me understand how can I achieve storing images on server?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=express+js+upload+file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `node.js` I recommend using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for uploading your files through it to server and then make a public link to your file and store that link in your database.